# ng-minlength breaking after deleting all text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to ensure a minimum length of input using `ng-minlength` however it seems to fail in one edge case. It correctly validates when adding or deleting characters, however it will incorrectly return to the valid state if the entire input is deleted.  Is this a known flaw, or am I using `ng-minlength` incorrectly?  below is my validator

```
<input name='projectName' type="text" data-ng-model="newProjectName" placeholder="Please add a project name" ng-minlength=4 ng-maxlength=17 ng-pattern="/[a-z0-9]/" ng-requrired="true"/>
```

Comment: can you provide some working example in jsfiddle or another tool?

Comment: heres an example, please excuse the lack of styling http://jsfiddle.net/3m921e9c/

Comment: @asa is right. You have to fix `ng-required` typo to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. `ng-requrired` should be `ng-required`.

Comment: thanks.  I'm dyslexic so I missed that. I'll accept in a few minutes

Comment: No worries. It's a mistake anyone can make :)